# SVG file not rendered

Tags: svg, gimp

I have a trouble opening an SVG file under my machine Linux:

Gave this svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="1000px" height="707px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
   <path id="MyPath" d="M 599,455 A 244,244 0 0,1 723,578" />
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"  />
<text font-family="Verdana" font-size="42.5" fill="blue" >
<textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
 We go up, then we go down, then up again
</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

If I open it with firefox I can see it, but If I open it with gimp for example, I can see nothing.

What part of that file is creating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you see no error, so I don't know if this is right:
If you built GIMP yourself, our are not using the system's GIMP for some
reason, there is a chance the devel-files for the SVG libs
were not present when GIMP was built. If taht is the case, it won't be able to 
read the SVG file itself.

You didn't say anything about error, so your might be another issue
(for example, the "Verdana" font might not be available for
GIMP, and it being replaced by a font with no visible glyphs)

In any case, the workaround would be to open the SVG file
in Inkscape, and export it as a raster PNG file for you
to work with it in GIMP>